# How do I change permission back to where it was?

Tags: root

I did a sudo chmod a+rwx /usr/local/java. After listing the ls -la, the (.) permission when from drwxr-xr-x to drwxrwxrwx. How do I change it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this explains the magic:

> drwxr-xr-x

translates in

> (rwx)(r-x) (r-x)

translates in

> (421) (401) (401)

translates in

> 755

So the answer is

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/java
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `chmod 755 /usr/local/java`

Comment: Most likely? Mmmm. Smells like a guess. Explain.

Comment: Just the way it is worded. I don't have to guess. Don't like the wording - edit. Smells like being bored.